# Loop through a directory and add filename to dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am rather new to Python and trying to learn this in my spare time. The goal of the task I am working on is to read a system directory and add the filename to a dictionary. I was able to just add it to a list, but I need to have a key that is an integer that I can use in a for loop. So after doing some reading, I think if I can loop through this directory and add an counter as the key and the filename as the value that would give me what I want. Here is what I have tried so far and if I am thinking about this the wrong way, please let me know. Also if I did not explain this clearly enough, I would be happy to try to provide more information. TYIA!

```
import os

def list_json_files():

    path_of_directory = 'C:\\JSON_Test\\json_files'
    list_of_files = {}
    ext = ('.json')

    for my_files in os.listdir(path_of_directory):
        if my_files.endswith(ext):
            # stuck and missing code 
        else:
            continue
    
    return list_of_files

list_json_files()

## added to code

def write_csv():
    list_of_files = list_json_files()
    for my_file in list_of_files:        
        row = create_list_from_json(f'json_files/{my_file}')  
        with open('output.csv', 'a') as c:
            writer = csv.writer(c)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: There's no need for a dict with int keys. Just use a list and then do `for index, filename in enumerate(list_of_files)`.

Comment: i added the code above and it doesn't seem to work...maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Remove `c.close()`. It's automatically closed by the 'with open' context manager.

Comment: @psuguy99 Actually, you don't need an index/counter at all. You can simply do `for my_file in list_of_files:` (assuming `list_json_files()` returns a list, and not a dict).

Comment: When I do that (if I remove enumerate), I get the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I appreciate you looking at this for me...I have been fumbling around with this for a couple hours. When I use the code you suggested, I get further along the for loop, but it adds this into the file name, which obviously messes up the path  (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "json_files/(0, 'sample 1.json')". However, it did get past the TypeError.

Comment: @psuguy99 That's because you are trying to use `my_file` as an index. But as I said before: you don't need indexes at all. If you use the *exact line* `for my_file in list_of_files:` in the code *as it is in your question*, it will work correctly.

Comment: @ekhumoro .... i was able to get this to work properly. The list indices error was when it was looping through the JSON file. I am working on that piece now and I will give it a go before I ask anyone on here. Thank you for your patience and your assistance!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, if your aim is to read list of files ending with .json and write it to a file.

**Code changes from the original**

1. Using glob, code is simpler to fetch files ending with particular extension. Hence using glob instead of os.listdir
2. Using normal file writer, instead of csv module, as I feel it would be sufficient for this scenario.

**Code**

```
import glob
import os.path

def list_json_files():
    path_of_directory = 'C:\\JSON_Test\\json_files'
    ext = ('*.json')
    list_of_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_of_directory, ext))
    return list_of_files

def write_csv():
    list_of_files = list_json_files()
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join(list_of_files))

write_csv()
```

Comment: I was able to use this method and it worked. I also got the other method to work that @ekhumoro posted. I appreciate all the assistance with this. Have a great day!